# Word 2013 page number issue

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, page-numbers

When using the page number system it duplicates one of the page numbers ie 1,2,3,4,5,5,6,7 etc

I have tried removing the footers formatting them and have looked rectified the headers also.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Does this happen in all word documents? Is this a newly created document or an existing one from a previous version of Word?

Comment: as far as we can tell yes. reasonably newly created.

Comment: Are all Office updates installed? Is this specific to one PC creating the document? If a properly working document from another PC is opened by the PC in question does the problem still exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out a link/content brought over from an exterior source had put a sort of page break in the document that messed up the page numbers.